# JOINING two tables to fetch COUNT from one and SUM from the other

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate

I am working on a project where users work on reports and enter details of their work in database. My database structure has two tables:

tbl_reports - this table contains all details of work performed

```
    report_id    user_id    date        country            status
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0001         abc        2014-05-04  USA                checked
    0002         abc        2014-05-04  USA                checked 
    0003         abc        2014-05-05  India              checked 
    0004         lmn        2014-05-04  USA                checked
    0005         lmn        2014-05-04  India              checked
    0006         xyz        2014-05-06  Taiwan             checked
```

tbl_time -  this table contains all details on time repoted by the users, date and country wise

```
    id    user_id    date        country     time (hrs)
    ----------------------------------------------------
    01    abc        2014-05-04  USA         4
    02    abc        2014-05-05  India       2
    03    lmn        2014-05-04  USA         3 
    04    lmn        2014-05-04  India       2
    05    opq        2014-05-05  Belgium     4
```

As you can see users "abc and "lmn" have tracked all their tasks appropriately while user "xyz" has not tracked his time yet and user "opq" has tracked his time but has no records of  reports he has worked on.

Now out of this I want to extract details of this team **GROUPING BY "date" and "country"** as below:

```
    date        country      total_report_count        total_time_count
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    2014-05-04  India        1                         2
    2014-05-04  USA          3                         7
    2014-05-05  Belgium      0                         4
    2014-05-05  India        1                         2
    2014-05-06  Taiwan       1                         0
```

Which means irrespective of which user has tracked his reports or time, I need to generate team report for worked done in which country on which date , its counts and total time tracked.

Now I was able to find total_time_count report using below code:

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_teamreport AS
    SELECT
    tb1.date , tb1.country,
    SUM(tb1.time) AS total_time_count 
    FROM tbl_time tb1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_reports tb2 
    ON tb2.report_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY tb1.date, tb1.country
    ORDER BY tb1.date, tb1.country;
```

Need help to complete the problem, and I am using MYSQL (*In case if FULL JOIN is required, FULL JOIN keyword is not supported*)

Comment: Off-topic small advice, next time use the highlight-code button, then you won't have to mess around with html tags and syntax highlighting yourself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no `FULL JOIN` you'll need a query to pull out all the distinct date/country combinations from the UNION of these two tables. Or, you'll need some other query to generate the full list of dates and countries. Call this query A.

You need to write two separate aggregating queries. One will aggregate the hours by date and country and the other will aggregate the reports by date and country. Call these queries B and C.

Then you need to do

```
  SELECT whatever, whatever
    FROM (
           /*query A*/
         ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN (
           /*query B*/
         ) AS b ON a.date=b.date AND a.country=b.country
    LEFT JOIN (
           /*query C*/
         ) AS c ON a.date=c.date AND a.country=c.country
```

This will produce a correctly summarized report with all the rows you need, and NULLs where there is missing summary data.

**Edit** 
Sorry, forgot about the nested query view restriction. You'll need to create four views, one for each subquery and one for the join query.  So it will be:

```
 CREATE VIEW dates_countries AS
      SELECT DISTINCT `date`, country FROM tbl_time
       UNION 
      SELECT DISTINCT `date`, country FROM tbl_reports;

 CREATE VIEW time_totals AS
      SELECT `date`, country, SUM(time) AS tot
        FROM tbl_time
       GROUP BY `date`, country

 CREATE VIEW report_totals AS
      SELECT `date`, country, COUNT(*) AS tot
        FROM tbl_reports
       GROUP BY `date`, country
```

And finally this view.

```
CREATE VIEW team_report AS
     SELECT a.`date`, a.country,
            c.tot AS total_report_count,
            b.tot AS total_time_count
       FROM dates_countries AS a
       LEFT JOIN time_totals AS b  ON a.`date` = b.`date` AND a.country = b.country
       LEFT JOIN repoorts_totals AS r  ON a.`date` = r.`date` AND a.country = r.country;
```

You don't have much choice about this when you need a view.

Comment: since this is in CREATE VIEW, we cannot use SUBquery in FROM CLAUSE,MYSQL does not support it

Comment: Oh, that's true. Forgot about that MySQL defect. See my edit.

Comment: nice one @OllieJones wish I can upvote more than once !

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty wait til you see how well it performs before upvoting too many times :-)  this kind of reporting is a bit messy.

Comment: @Ollie I have used VIEWS because whenever report has to be pulled out it must be up-to-date. A stored procedure would require UPDATE query first then select that too based on user event like button click and trigger would create mess if it would fire on every INSERT in each of these tables, so I chose VIEWS.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a divide it into two sub-queries with each section providing one of the reporting data like this,

```
CREATE VIEW vw_teamreport AS

SELECT tt.date, tt.country, t1.total_time_count, t2.total_report_count
FROM
(SELECT distinct tb1.date , tb1.country
FROM tbl_time tb1 
UNION
SELECT tb1.date , tb1.country
FROM tbl_reports tb1 
) tt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT tb1.date , tb1.country, SUM(tb1.time) AS total_time_count
FROM tbl_time tb1 
GROUP BY tb1.date, tb1.country) t1
    ON tt.date = t1.date and tt.country = t1.country
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT tb1.date , tb1.country, COUNT(tb1.country) AS total_report_count
FROM tbl_reports tb1 
GROUP BY tb1.date, tb1.country)t2
ON tt.date = t2.date and tt.country = t2.country
```

The first query provides the union for all time & country. The 2nd and the 3rd query provides the report data.

Comment: since this is in CREATE VIEW, we cannot use SUBquery in FROM CLAUSE, MYSQL does not support it! http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16757

Comment: @dexterslab: Checking for other solutions now

Comment: @dexterslab: How about creating a stored procedure that takes no parameters and make it look like a view?